# How to get redirected to a particular tab in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6

There are 4 tabs on a particular URL and the first one is marked active by default.
I want to get another tab in an active state on the occurrence of a particular event while getting redirected to this URL.

I've already tried solutions like:

1. `$('[href="#transaction_history"]').tab('show');`
2. `$('.nav nav-pills nav-stacked a[href="#transaction_history"]').tab('show')`
3. `$('.nav-stacked > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');`
4. `$('.nav-stacked li:eq(2) a').tab('show')`

None of these have worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage this via flag. and based on that you have apply class dynamically.

```
[ngClass]="{'active':tab == 'xtabName'}"
```